# Can SQL Reporting Services 2008 integrate with a SharePoint 2007 installation running SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, moss

We have a production MOSS 2007 environment installed with SQL Server 2005. Is it possible to configure an instance of Reporting Services 2008 to operate in SharePoint integrated mode with MOSS on SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the below links can help you:

[Integrating Reporting Services 2008 with SharePoint 2007](http://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2009/01/integrating-sql-server-2008-reporting.html)

[Reporting Services and SharePoint Technology Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326358.aspx)

[SharePoint and SQL Server Reporting Services - Installation and Setup](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-12-SharePoint_and_SQL_Server_Reporting_Services_-_Installation_and_Setup.aspx)